# How i can find th element by class name with spaces using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i know that selenium have a find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME) method and it good works with simple name classes witout spaces but i have an element `<button type="button" class="type active" id="getTimetable" data-type="group" data-date="sunday">На завтра</button>`

and i do not know how to write this because i have an Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
tomorow_btn = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='button[class="type active"]')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response   
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[class="type active"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=_ipadress_); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7ECCF8EF2+54786]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECC65612]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECB1A64B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECB5B79C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECB5B91C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECB96D87]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECB7BEAF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECB94D02]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECB7BC43]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECB50941]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECB51B84]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7ED047F52+3524194]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7ED09D800+3874576]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7ED095D7F+3843215]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7ECD95086+694166]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECC70A88]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECC6CA94]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECC6CBC2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7ECC5CC83]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFC164D54E0+16]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFC183C485B+43]
```

if it is possible, please solve the problem without xpath

I have seen people use *.* instead of a space, but with *.* i have the same error

i use the Python 3.12.0 and Selenium 4.14.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing

`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.type.active')` instead of

`driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='button[class="type active"]')`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is because the button element has multiple classes, and the button[class="type active"] selector is looking for an exact match to the class attribute. When you specify class="type active", it expects the class attribute to be exactly "type active," which is not the case because there are multiple classes.

To select an element with multiple classes, you can use a CSS selector by specifying both classes with a period (.) as a class selector. Here's the corrected CSS selector for your button element:

```
tomorow_btn = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='button.type.active')
```

This selector finds a button element with the classes type and active, and it should work in your case.

If you prefer not to use CSS selectors, you can use find_element_by_class_name to find elements by a single class name. In your case, you can use it like this:

```
tomorow_btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name("type")
```

However, this approach works for individual classes. If you need to find an element with multiple classes like "type active," using a CSS selector with periods is the recommended approach.